# Mass assignment error with nested fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mass-assignment

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times.  I already have nested `fields_for` in my app many times w/o issue so I'm confused as to why its not working this time. I apologize for bringing this topic up again.

I have a user model.  A user can have many accounts.  To prevent a user from existing w/o at least one account I have a `semantic_fields_for` nested in the new user form with just one input for setting account `role_id`.

#### class User

```
    attr_accessible :accounts_attributes
    has_many :accounts, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts
```

#### class Account

```
    attr_accessible :role_id, :user_id, :status
    belongs_to :role
    belongs_to :user
```

#### users/new

```
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :accounts do |account| %>
    <%= account.input :role, :as => :select, :collection => @roles, :label => "Account" %>
    <% end %>
```

So, to recap: I have the association set up between users and accounts, users model includes `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, users model includes `attr_accessible :accounts_attributes`, `semantic_fields_for` is set up correctly. The error I get is:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: accounts

The stack trace from the submitted form includes all the correct variables.  Account `role_id` is being set correctly by the nested attribute.  The record is simply being rejected for mass-assignment error but it sure seems my attributes are all properly protected.

Using Rails 3.2.3 and Formtastic 2.2.

EDITED

**class UsersController**

def new

```
  @user = User.new         
  @user.accounts.build
```

end

**users/new**

```
    <%= semantic_form_for :user, :url => users_path do |f| -%>
    
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :username %>
    <%= f.input :email %>   
        <%= f.input :password, :as => :password %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => "Confirm Password", :as => :password %>
    <%= f.input :school_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => @school.id} %>        

        <%= f.semantic_fields_for :accounts do |account| %>
          <%= account.input :role_id, :as => :select, :collection => @roles %>
        <% end %>

    <%- end -%> <%# END f.inputs do %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Create User', :class => "button" %>
    <%- end -%> <%# END form %>
```

Comment: parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"sYJJpQyxBEIUL0tYvCed1t818/zjwKuMMdwOL8JQtqk=",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"asdf adf",
 "username"=>"aadf",
 "email"=>"qsdf@adf.com",
 "certificatenumber"=>"",
 "certificateexp(1i)"=>"",
 "certificateexp(2i)"=>"",
 "certificateexp(3i)"=>"1",
 "medical_id"=>"",
 "medicalissuedate"=>"",
 "birthdate"=>"",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "school_id"=>"27",
 "accounts"=>{"role"=>"2"}},
 "commit"=>"Create User"}

Comment: If I remove attr_accessible completely to bypass mass-assignment I get the following error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in UsersController#create

Account(#70248725912340) expected, got Array(#70248703455660)

Comment: I changed the nested field to be :role_id.  Its not totally necessary using formtastic but didn't want that to cause confusion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!! I removed :url => and changed :user to @user in the semantic_form_for block... I guess the way I had it was causing the params[:account] to set off mass assignment

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your to your User class

```
attr_accessible :accounts_attributes
```

Comment: it seems like formtastic isn't sending the proper attributes. Normally in your params you should see something like accounts_attributes => {"0" => {"role"=>"2"}, "1" => {"role" => "3"}}

Comment: Try posting your whole formatastic code anad maybe the code you use to 'build' accounts for user

Comment: I added 'account_ids' to attr_accessible in the User model in an attempt to make sure all bases are covered for its mass assignment

Comment: GOT IT!!  I removed :url => and changed :user to @user in the semantic_form_for block...  I guess the way I had it was causing the params[:account] to set off mass assignment.